# Javascript: How to append hidden input tag into a form when submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, input

I have variable name and value for hidden input tag that I want to append into form right when submit button is clicked. How do I go about coding it?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

hname="reference";
hvalue="1";

function insertInput(){
document.write( "<input type='hidden' name='" + hname + " ' value=' " + hvalue + " '/><br/>");
}

</script>


<form id="form1">
    <p><label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" size="10"/></p>
    <p><label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" size="10"/></p>

    <p id="hidden"><!-- Insert Hidden input tag here --></p>

    <button type="submit' onClick="insertInput();">Log In</button>  
</form>
```

I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: Never use `document.write`, unless you are using a time machine to send this code back to 1996...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="form1">
        <p><label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" size="10" /></p>
        <p><label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" size="10" /></p>

        <p id="hidden"><!-- Insert Hidden input tag here --></p>

        <button type="submit" onclick="return insertInput();">Log In</button>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

    hname="reference";
    hvalue="1";

    function insertInput(){
        var para, hiddenInput, br;
        para = document.getElementById('hidden');
        hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.type = 'hidden';
        hiddenInput.name = hname;
        hiddenInput.value = hvalue;
        para.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        br = document.createElement('br'); //Not sure why you needed this <br> tag but here it is
        para.appendChild(br);

        return false; //Have this function return true if you want to post right away after adding the hidden value, otherwise leave it to false
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This one seems to work. Thanks man! One more question... How do I go about setting it to auto increment if I have the variable hname and hvalue equal to array like:

hname=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Toyota"];
hvalue=["Sports","Luxury","Premium","Hybrid"];

Comment: I guess you want to first send BMW, then Volvo, then Saab, then Toyota. Try having hiddenInput.name = hname[index] and hiddenInput.value = hvalue[index] and then increment index every time you call the function (be careful if you call it more than a certain amount of times (i.e. the length of the array, in this case 4) then you would get an array of out bounds error).

Answer (score 3):

`document.write()` only works while the document is being parsed. As soon as the document is in ready state (i.e. the `DOMContentLoaded` event has been fired), `document.write` will implicitly call `document.open()`, which in turn resets your document.

You want to use the DOM methods for this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'hidden';
  input.name = 'reference';
  input.value = '1';
  this.appendChild(input);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because `document.write` only works while the page is loading, trying to use it after the page has loaded will fail.

You could do it with pure DOM scripting but I would suggest using a DOM library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), they make doing things like this much easier.

Here's a way you could do it with jQuery:

```
<form id="form1">
    <p><label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" size="10"/></p>
    <p><label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" size="10"/></p>

    <button type="submit">Log In</button>  
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var hname = "reference",
        hvalue = "1";

    $("#form1").on("submit", function () {
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='" + hname + " ' value=' " + hvalue + " '/><br/>");
    });
});

</script>
```