# Jquery - add value before submit

Tags: jquery

The user is submitting a single value using a GET method. I want to add a value from the template to pass to the server. In this example the value is "budweiser"

I have tried a number of variations on the below, but the only thing that gets passed to the server is the parameter in the form.

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                                     
$('#form1').submit(function(){                                                                                                                                             
$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="budweiser">');                                                                                                                               
  return true;                                                                                                                                                            
</script> 

<form id="form1" action="/dashboard_single/" method="get">                                                                                                                 
<input type="integer" name ="dash_days">                                                                                                      
<input type="submit" value="Go">                                                                                                                                         
 </form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283945/javascript-how-to-append-hidden-input-tag-into-a-form-when-submit-button-is-cli/15284398 is a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much more to do from your current code. The following should work:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    $('#form1').append('<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="budweiser">');
});
```

You will see that the `filter` param is passed with the value "budweiser".

```js
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    $('#form1').append('<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="budweiser">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="/dashboard_single/" method="get">
  <input type="integer" name="dash_days">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just can't get it to work for now. Copied it exactly and still just get just the one parameter. Mystified.

Comment: OK, I had the <script> function BEFORE the form. Moved it to after the form and all good. So dumb, thanks a lot.